# SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user MySQL error

Tags: mysql, laravel, ubuntu

I get the following error.

> SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'snapsell'@'localhost'
> (using password: YES) (SQL: select * from `menulist`)

I have tried the following.

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-server
sudo apt-get install mysql-client
sudo apt-get install php-mysql
sudo apt-get install phpmyadmin
sudo mysql_secure_installation
mysql -u root -p
mysql> CREATE USER 'pmauser'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'password_here';

mysql> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'pmauser'@'localhost';
mysql> FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
mysql> exit
```

The user is already created; I can use those credentials for PHPMyAdmin. However, I can't use it on Laravel to connect MySQL on Ubuntu Digital Ocean. And I have set them on the Laravel .env file, but I am unsure what the issue is.

Comment: try with 127.0.0.1 hope it will work

Comment: instead of `localhost` try `%`, so `'pmauser'@'%'`

Comment: I have tried 127.0.0.1 and %.
But they are not working yet.

Comment: My friend tell me like this.
**The problem on apache
Need enable module php
Need to enable php-mysql
And mysql need to set native plugins pasword 
Then disable ssl login**

But I am not sure how can I do. There is any suggestion for it?

Comment: Can you post your `.env` file please?

Comment: This is my .env file screenshot
https://prnt.sc/19w7x4n

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to change your `DB_USERNAME` value to `"pmauser"` inside your `/.env` file (on your Laravel project root) and try again, it will looks like:

```
# ...

DB_USERNAME=pmauser

# ...
```

Comment: Sorry
I have already changed it.
https://prnt.sc/19w7x4n
This is my .env file screenshot.

Comment: in this screen shot, it is not changed

Comment: bro, you have to change to `pmauser` because it's the name of the user that you've created with `CREATE USER 'pmauser'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'password_here';` MySQL command

Comment: https://prnt.sc/19welgj
As you can see there are already the user.

If possible can you help me via anydesk. 
It think it is comfortable for you to check it directly.

If so, I will be very happy.
Thank you

Comment: sorry, I cannot help with anydesk, btw from de print seems that you user doesn't have grant permissions